# Totally confused between GTK, GTK +, GTK + 3, PyGobject, etc

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to find out if I can write python-based windows desktop widgets using python 3.2.2 or higher for windows. The above projects are thoroughly confusing. Do any of them support what I'm looking for? (i.e. can be used with windows and python 3.2.2 and higher?

I did come across this answer (https://askubuntu.com/questions/97023/why-cant-i-import-pygtk-with-python-3-2-from-pydev) but it looks like it only works for non-windows platform.

If non of these above python-projects will work with windows and python 3.2.2, is there an easier way to create rainmeter-like desktop widgets in python 3.2.2 or higher for windows?

Comment: When you say "windows desktop widgets", do you mean the things that show up in the side bar? I'm not sure those can be done using GTK at all.

Comment: No not necessarily. In fact, I don't intend for it to work with windows sidebar at all. I just want to be able to create a custom looking, partially transparent UI that sits on windows desktop that displays data (like CPU, RAM, data etc.). Something like this would just be an example: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_ZQvPgJCHQr0/TGq_28bzMmI/AAAAAAAAAJk/Q1UM_K1DZTE/s1600/My+theme+2.jpg

Comment: Relegating my previous answer to a comment, in the hope that others may make more relevant suggestions: Do you need it to be Python 3.X? wxPython can [create transparent frames](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Transparent%20Frames), but only supports Python 2.x

Comment: It's hard to get an up-to-date version of pygtk on windows... Last trick I saw was to rip it out of GIMP installer!

Comment: http://opensourcepack.blogspot.com.au/p/pygobject-pygi-aio.html

Answer (score 1):

To start with the confusion: Gtk is the [GIMP toolkit](http://www.gtk.org/), and all the different things you mention in your question title are related, but not quite the same. PyGTK is the legacy binding between Python and GTK, and PyGObject is the preferred binding if you go down that road.

Here a [nice short overview](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/gui/) of all the different GUI options for Python development, that should explain those terms briefly so that you have an overview. And as gauden suggested in the comments, wxPython is a very common road for cross-platform applications.

Nowadays you should at least consider [Kivy](http://kivy.org) as well, it is fun to program in, and it even gives you options to expand the "cross-platform" bit to mobile devices. It supports transparency ([or opacity in Kivy terms](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.html?highlight=opacity#kivy.graphics.Canvas.opacity))

Comment: @hbdgaf Somewhere in the early nineties the GIMP developers designed their own widget toolkit and called it GIMP Toolkit. Since then both projects both grew substantially, and the GIMP Toolkit is now GTK+ supporting much much more than just GIMP. I will add a link to the answer above.